# How to make a php request report failure

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm trying to scan the files in a directory using a php request. This is my code right now:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scandir.php",

    data: { dirname: "./test" },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }   
    error: function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    }
});
```

---

scandir.php:

```
<?php
    $dirname = $_POST[ "dirname" ];
    $files = scandir( $dirname ) or die("Unable to scan directory " . $dirname );
    foreach ( $files as $filename ) {
    echo $filename . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Problem is, the request always returns successfully, even if the directory "dirname" doesn't exist (it returns the text of the php directory-not-found messages). How do I make it return with an error when the directory is not found?

Comment: What is the output that you are getting ?

Comment: please add a comma after the success entry

Comment: Why don't you check to see if the directory exists first before using `scandir`? If it does not, you can return whatever it is you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST["dirname"])) {
    $dirname = $_POST["dirname"];

    if(!is_dir($dirname)) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit;
    }
    foreach(scandir($dirname) as $filename) {
        echo $filename . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the header text to be more specific

header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Directory Not Found: " . $dirname)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the `error` entry is only for http errors like timeout or 404 not found. If you want to check if the php script failed internally, you either can set a header using php's method `header` or you check in the success function whether the php script returned an error. Hope that helps.